not able to solve :appdebugRuntimeClasspath issue in android
The error is :
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
I am using Hilt dagger with the given build.gradle dependencies and other details :
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.tweetsy2"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.tweetsy2"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "19"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.11"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    val lifecycle_version = "2.7.0"
    //Lifecycle
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")


    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycle utilities for Compose
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycle_version")


 //Hilt
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.51.1")


    //Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.1-Beta")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.8.1-Beta")




    //Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.11.0")




    //Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")


}



How to handle this issue. I am solving it for like 2 days. Still no resolution.
I tried doing build.gradle dependency version changes, kotlin version changes, jvmtarget changes.
